# Optimizing matrix writes in python/numpy

Tags: python, performance, optimization, numpy, matrix

I'm currently trying to optimize a piece of code the gist of it is we go through and compute a bunch of values and write them to a matrix. The order of computation doesn't matter:

```
mat =  np.zeros((n, n))
mat.fill(MAX_VAL)
for i in xrange(0, smallerDim):
    for j in xrange(0,n):
        similarityVal = doACalculation(i,j, data, cache)
        mat[i][j] = abs(1.0 / (similarityVal + 1.0))
```

I've profiled this code and have found that approximately 90% of the time is spent on writing the value back into the matrix (the last line)

I'm wondering what the optimal way to do this type of computation to optimize the writes. Should I write to an intermediate buffer and copy in the whole row etc etc. I'm a bit clueless to performance tuning or numpy internals.

EDIT:
doACalculation is not a side-effect free function. It takes in some data (assume this is some python object) and also a cache to which it writes and reads some intermediate steps. I'm not sure if it can easily be vectorized. I tried using numpy.vectorize as recommended but did not see a significant speedup over the naive for loop. (I passed in the additional data via a state variable):

Comment: try `numpy.vectorize`

Comment: What's `doACalculation`?

Comment: As a general comment, you'll get better performance using `mat[i,j]` rather than `mat[i][j]`, but that improvement will be small vs using numpy broadcasting and ufuncs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can vectorize `doACalculation`, the task becomes easy:

```
similarityArray = doACalculation(np.indices((smallerDim, n)))
mat[:smallerDim] = np.abs(1.0 / (similarityArray + 1))
```

This should be at least an order of magnitude faster, assuming you vectorize `doACalculation` properly. Generally, when working with NumPy arrays, you want to avoid explicit loops and element accesses as much as possible.

For reference, an example vectorization of a possible `doACalculation`:

```
# Unvectorized
def doACalculation(i, j):
    return i**2 + i*j + j

# Vectorized
def doACalculation(input):
    i, j = input
    return i**2 + i*j + j

# Vectorized, but with the original call signature
def doACalculation(i, j):
    return i**2 + i*j + j
```

Yes, the last version really is supposed to be identical to the unvectorized function. It sometimes is that easy.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping it in a numba autojit should improve the performance quite a bit.

```
def doACalculationVector(n, smallerDim):
    return np.ones((smallerDim, n)) + 1


def testVector():
    n = 1000
    smallerDim = 800
    mat =  np.zeros((n, n))
    mat.fill(10) 
    mat[:smallerDim] = abs(1.0 / (doACalculationVector(n, smallerDim) + 1.0))
    return mat

@numba.autojit
def doACalculationNumba(i,j):
    return 2

@numba.autojit
def testNumba():
    n = 1000
    smallerDim = 800
    mat =  np.zeros((n, n))
    mat.fill(10)
    for i in xrange(0, smallerDim):
        for j in xrange(0, n):
            mat[i,j] = abs(1.0 / (doACalculationNumba(i, j) + 1.0))
    return mat
```

Original Timing for reference: (with `mat[i][j]` changed to `mat[i,j]`)

```
In [24]: %timeit test()
1 loops, best of 3: 226 ms per loop
```

Now i simplified the function a bit since this was all that was provided. But testNumba was about **40 times as fast as test** when timed. and about **3 times as fast as the vectorized**

```
In [20]: %timeit testVector()
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit testNumba()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: Because the OP is asking for the optimal way to do a calculation with numpy. This is certainly going to be accomplished by vectorizing the calculations, not by getting a 2x speedup using a jit compiler.

Comment: Just as a side note, one little change to your code will result in a dramatic improvement. For me, your original code gives 629 ms vs 321 ms for the pure python vs numba, respectively. If you change `mat[i][j] = ...` to `mat[i,j] = ...` the timing changes to 295 ms vs 9 ms for python vs jit'd. In general you should always use `[i,j,k]` vs `[i][j][k]` to index into numpy arrays, whether you are using straight numpy or numba.

Comment: @jterrace without knowing what the "doACalculation" function does, we can't know if that function is easily\possible to vectorize. numba autojit will always give some performance boost, and it's a one liner so it's basically free.

Comment: If it's faster than the line right after, it's unlikely to be too complex, at least.

Comment: I'm surprised changing the indexing resulted in such a dramatic improvement. How fast does this run if `doACalculation` is an actual function, rather than an inlined constant? (It might as well still return 2 if you want.)

Comment: 192ms vs 235ms  with a function simply returning 2. but if i also autojit that function it's down to 6ms.

Comment: 4ms is impressive - compare to vectorized and you've got my +1

Comment: @jterrace Comparing to vectorized added

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can't vectorize `doACalculation()`. You can use `numpy.vectorize()` to
speed the calculation. Here is the test.

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000
smallerDim = 500

def doACalculation(i, j):
    return i+j
```

For loop version:

```
%%timeit
mat =  np.zeros((n, n))

for i in xrange(0, smallerDim):
    for j in xrange(0,n):
        similarityVal = doACalculation(i,j)
        mat[i,j] = abs(1.0 / (similarityVal + 1.0))
```

output:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 183 ms per loop
```

`vectorize()` version:

```
%%timeit
mat2 =  np.zeros((n, n))
i, j = np.ix_(np.arange(smallerDim), np.arange(n))
f = np.vectorize(doACalculation, "d")
mat2[:smallerDim] = np.abs(1.0/(f(i, j) + 1))
```

output:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 97.3 ms per loop
```

Test result:

```
np.allclose(mat,mat2)
```

outpout:

```
True
```

This method doesn't make `doACalculation()` calling much faster, but it make it possible that subsequent calculation can be done vectorized.

Comment: I'm looking into this further. One thing to note is that doACalculation depends on some additional state beyond i and j (some other data elements) ... is there a way to pass that information as well?